# не запускается активити, вылетает с ошибкой

Tags: java, xml, listview

В main2activity есть listview. Listview состоит из 200 item, которые хранятся в массиве table1 из файла string.xml. Пользователь выбирает несколько item и посредством btnchecked выбранные позиции отправляются в активити table. При переходе из mainactivity в main2activity вылетает с ошибкой.

Код main2activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ListView LV_main;
String[] table1;
Button btnChecked;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

LV_main = (ListView) LV_main.findViewById(R.id.LV_main);
LV_main.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

int n = 0;
LV_main.smoothScrollToPosition(n);

btnChecked = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChecked);
btnChecked.setOnClickListener(this);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.table1,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice);
LV_main.setAdapter(adapter);


table1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.table1);

}
@Override

public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnChecked:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Table1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
}
```

Разметка main2activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChecked"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next">
</Button>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/LV_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@id/LV_main"
    >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Логи

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.#####.#####, PID: 4406

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 

ComponentInfo{com.#####.#####/com.#####.#####.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ListView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ListView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

at com.#####.#####.Main2Activity.<init>(Main2Activity.java:21)

at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)

at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 

at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Стектрейс то покажите и укажите номер строки, на которой падает.

Comment: Suvitruf, Добавил логи

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^"

Answer (score 0):

У вас обращение к методу `findViewById` объекта, который вы ещё не инициализировали:

```
LV_main = (ListView) LV_main.findViewById(R.id.LV_main);
```

Подозреваю, что там должно быть просто:

```
LV_main = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LV_main);
```

Comment: Suvitruf, не работает

Comment: @Ahillesius какая ошибка?

Comment: Запустил на другом устройстве и заработало